# Set Content-Type without parameters

Tags: javascript, express, json-api

The [JSON API spec](http://jsonapi.org/format/#content-negotiation) mentions:

> Servers **MUST** send all JSON API data in response documents with the header `Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json` without any media type parameters.

When I set the content type in express using `res.set( "Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json" );`, express will automatically add the `charset=utf-8` parameter on the content type. This makes the response not spec compliant.

I tried setting the header more directly by using `res.setHeader`, but the result is identical.

How do I properly set the response content type without parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.send()` is what adds the `charset`; you’ll have to use `res.end()` manually.

Comment: I also saw the adjustment in the `send` method, but did not come to a good solution. I do not see how `res.end()` will help though. I am not experimenting with `res.send( new Buffer( JSON.stringify( result ), "utf-8" ) );`. So far, that seems like the only thing that has the desired result. BTW, I saw your P.S. and would love to hear your argument on chat, if you have the time :)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: Sorry, `res.end(JSON.stringify(result))` is what I meant, specifically – does it not work?

Comment: Not sure what I did wrong when I tried it earlier. I just tried it again and it works perfectly. Thanks for following up.